# twitter bootstrap popover displaying but looks weird - rails

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, popover

Hi I'm using twitter bootstrap popover functionality with seyhunak / twitter-bootstrap-rails gem.

I have the following code in my view:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills subnav">
  <li>
    <a class="label-with-popover" data-content="popover content" data-title="popover title">Home Valuations:</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The following in my page.js.coffe

```
jQuery ->
$('.label-with-popover').popover()
```

The popover appears but looks like so:

[image: Bootstrap popover displays weird with extra vertical line through it]

Bootstrap popover displays weird with extra vertical line through it: does anyone know how I can fix this?

Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: You may have some conflicting CSS. It would be best if you tried to reproduce this issue in JSFiddle or CodePen for us.

Comment: No success on jsfiddle. Any hints as to what kind of things might be clashing with this?

Comment: Try sourcing all of your CSS files in the jsfiddle, and then removing them one by one!

Comment: I appreciate the help so far @zetlen. So I got it up on jsfiddle check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/beamon/5rT9t/. I'm going to keep try finding the issue, here is the link if you wish to lend a hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a bunch of collisions between Bootstrap CSS and the CSS you wrote for your project. In the future, you should consider using a namespace for your own general-purpose classes like `.arrow`, or your CSS will interfere with third-party libraries (like Bootstrap) which use such common class names.

Here's an edit to your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5rT9t/1/

I removed the `margin` declaration on `.content`, the `padding` values on `.arrow`, and, strictly for demo, added a container div to offset the popover so you could see the whole thing.

Comment: You beat me to it. Thanks for the lesson.